# How can I create a stringified query string of array values?

Tags: javascript

What I ultimately want to have is:

```
import qs as 'qs'

qs.stringify({
      country: 'us',
      currency: 'USD',
      'kw[]': 'apple',
      'kw[]': 'banana',
      'kw[]': 'pear',
    })
```

But currently, I have:

```
const keywords = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear']
```

How can I convert that to the `kw[]` syntax?

Comment: I would use `reduce` personally. You can reduce the array to an object.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Not right now no. The key is to return an object and not an array from the reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import qs from 'qs';
const keywords = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear'];
const queryObject = { country: 'us', currency: 'USD', kw: keywords };
const queryString = qs.stringify(queryObject);
console.log(queryString);
```

The above will output:

```
country=us&currency=USD&kw%5B0%5D=apple&kw%5B1%5D=banana&kw%5B2%5D=pear
```

Decoded, it looks like this:

```
country=us&currency=USD&kw[0]=apple&kw[1]=banana&kw[2]=pear
```